# Font issue while porting to .Net 6 framework

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have created a sample app in Winforms running on .NET 4.7.1 printing a graphic font in image. Code is written in `Paint` handler of form as follows:

```
private void Form1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
        System.Drawing.Graphics graphicsObj;

        graphicsObj = this.CreateGraphics();

        Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 12);

        Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

        graphicsObj.DrawString("Hello C#", myFont, myBrush, 30, 30);        

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(200), Convert.ToInt32(200), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

        // Add drawing commands here
        g.DrawString("Hello C#", myFont, myBrush, 30, 30);

        bitmap.Save(@"net45.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

We are porting this code to .NET 6.0 without changing anything. But the font size is different in both case.

It seems the height property in .NET 4.5

[image: .net 4.5 font]

is different from the height used in .NET 6.0

[image: .net 6.0 font]

How to make both font sizes the same?

We tried changing font constructor parameters, font family but result is coming same as above.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.sethighdpimode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0

Comment: Hi I tried this approach by adding following line
Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2);
Still issue is still existing.